# Textbook for understanding formal grammars

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, reference-request, books

I am looking to understand the Chomsky Hierarchy. I've read some textbooks that *touch* on formal grammars (textbooks on computability, which relate automata to specific sets of formal grammars, notably context-free grammars and regular grammars), but not one that specifically deals with formal grammars as an object.

Is there a good textbook for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the most-used textbook today is:

- Hopcroft, Motwani, & Ullman, *Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation* (3rd edition).

A couple of other common ones are:

- Sipser, Introduction to the Theory of Computation.
- Linz, An Introduction to Formal Languages and Automata.

And a couple of older ones:

- Michael Harrison, *Introduction to Formal Language Theory*. Many learned from this 1978 classic. Even though it's older, it has the advantage that you can pick up a very inexpensive used copy from online retailers.
- Thomas Sudkamp, *Languages and Machines: An Introduction to the Theory of Computer Science*. It's up to the 3rd edition now, but the first edition was my textbook when I was an undergraduate. The exercises are excellent, but it's light on examples.