# Does Sipser's _Introduction to the Theory of Computation_ cover the Chomsky hierarchy?

Tags: automata, reference-request, chomsky-hierarchy, reference-question

I saw the book suggested [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/119084/textbook-for-understanding-formal-grammars).

Does Sipser's *Introduction to the Theory of Computation* cover the Chomsky hierarchy?

I ask since, looking through a pdf copy of the book, I found no matches with "Chomsky Hierarchy", but perhaps it is covered with a different name.

Comment: I reviewed every page of that textbook basically before I wrote my answer. Is it convincing enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Sipser's textbook does not cover Chomsky hierarchy, a containment hierarchy of different classes of formal grammars. Nor does it cover that hierarchy with a different name.  In fact, the book does not mention any formal grammar other than context-free grammar.

That textbook does cover many [related concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy#The_hierarchy) such as regular language and finite state automaton, context-free grammar and context-free language and non-deterministic pushdown automaton, linear-bounded deterministic Turing machine, recursively enumerable and Turing machine. It certainly covers context-free grammar pretty well. It is not surprising the post linked in the question recommends it for understanding formal grammars.